# npm install not working on ubuntu ERR EMISSINGARG

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, ubuntu-18.04

Linux 4.15.0, I'm trying to run code from my branch on github. It's a webpack setup project. Not Create-react-app. Runs fine on windows. Throws **EMISSINGARG** code error on 4.15.0-109-generic ubuntu.

Using node v8.10.0, npm v3.5.2. Project locally is on my /Documents. Using Vs code Editor. Tried regular linux terminal too.

Details :

[image]

Comment: Well. First line is: `wanted: {"node": ">=8", "npm": ">=6"}` and you have npm version `3.5.2`. Try to instal later version. Though I'm very curious how you installed "node v8.10.0, npm v3.5.2.". [For node version `8.10.0` you supposed to have npm version `5.6.0`](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)

Comment: Thanks Buddy. To your curiosity, I did the project setup on windows as I have both Windows and Linux on my machine. Thx it was quite helpful.